# How is MTD partition layout detected/parsed in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, flash-memory, device-tree

I am working on an embedded Linux system, which uses kernel-5.10.24.
There is a NAND FLASH used as storage in system, and it has 4 partitons.  When the kernel boots up, there shows 4 partitions as follows,

```
[    0.499555] Creating 4 MTD partitions on "spi_nand":
[    0.499564] 0x000000000000-0x000000080000 : "uboot"
[    0.501099] 0x000000080000-0x000000900000 : "kernel"
[    0.510556] 0x000000900000-0x000007000000 : "filesys"
[    0.580413] 0x000007000000-0x000008000000 : "app"
```

How does the kernel know the NAND FLASH's MTD partions?

**My main purpose is to speed up kernel booting by removing MTD partion scanning.**

I found there is NAND partition definition in the device tree, but the layout is different from the real system.

```
    nandflash@0 {
        partitions {
            compatible = "fixed-partitions";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;

            /* spi nand flash partition */
            partition@0 {
                label = "uboot";
                reg = <0x0000000 0xE0000>;
                /*read-only;*/
            };

            partition@E0000 {
                label = "kernel";
                reg = <0xE0000 0x900000>;
            };

            partition@900000 {
                label = "filesys";
                reg = <0x900000 0x8000000>;
            };
        };
    };
```

Is it possible to ask kernel to parse/get the partition infor from the device tree? If so, how to do that?
Is it possible to speed kernel booting up by using the hard-coded partition info in device tree?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the code of parsing NAND partitions through device tree, I found it is a bug in vendor's code to do partition probing and parsing. By fixing the bug it worked as expected.